# Get current working directory of another process

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a PID, and I am trying to determine what the current working directory of the process is. I played around with `wmic process` for a while, but it doesn't seem to have the cwd available. Anyone know of a clever way that I can accomplish this?

Comment: Answered on [so]: [windows batch command to determine working directory of a process - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576834/windows-batch-command-to-determine-working-directory-of-a-process)

Comment: Both of the given answers seem to require downloading a separate utility (tlist or handle). I was really hoping for a built-in so the solution would be portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this batch script with admin rights for execution :

```dos
@echo off
Mode 75,8 & color 0A
Title Get ExecutablePath of any PID by Hackoo 2018
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
REM  --> Check for permissions
Reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19\Environment" >nul 2>&1
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
Echo.
ECHO                 **************************************
ECHO                  Running Admin shell... Please wait...
ECHO                 **************************************

    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:Loop
Cls
echo( 
set /P "PID=Please provide a PID number to get its ExecutablePath : "
set "ExePath="
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('"wmic process where "ProcessID^=!PID!" get ExecutablePath 2^>nul"') do (
    If Not "!errorlevel!" equ "1" (
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do if not defined ExePath set "ExePath=%%b"
        Rem To trim a variable ( Removing Spaces into a variable )
        set "ExePath=!ExePath: =!"
    )
)

echo ExecutablePath ==^> "!ExePath!"
for %%a in ("!ExePath!") do set "CWD=%%~dpa"
echo Current Working Directory ==^> "!cwd!"
echo(
echo Hit any key to choose another PID & pause>nul & goto Loop
```

Comment: That's impressive batch scripting, but the OP was looking for a process' _working directory_, not its executable's path.